# Gazebo cannot launch: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, ros, ubuntu-20.04

I can't launch gazebo on my Ubuntu terminal.

I tried gazebo --verbose

But the following error displayed:

```
[Msg] Waiting for master.
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.3.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 172.17.250.168
[Err] [RenderEngine.cc:749] Can't open display:
[Wrn] [RenderEngine.cc:89] Unable to create X window. Rendering will be disabled
[Wrn] [RenderEngine.cc:292] Cannot initialize render engine since render path type is NONE. Ignore this warning ifrendering has been turned off on purpose.
[Msg] Loading world file [/usr/share/gazebo-11/worlds/empty.world]
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 172.17.250.168
```

Answer (score 0):

Which ROS distro are you using it with? How have you installed it? (Source or binary)

If you have built it from source, I would strongly recommend re-installing it again.

Answer (score 0):

The error message makes a lot of sense,

> [Err] [RenderEngine.cc:749] Can't open display: [Wrn]
> [RenderEngine.cc:89] Unable to create X window. Rendering will be
> disabled

Display server is a program that serves display screen to GUI programs. Basically Gazebo requires a running [display server](https://itsfoss.com/display-server/),

1. To visualize the simulation on Gazebo GUI client
2. To generate output from some sensors like camera

Linux can have multiple display servers running at the sametime and it is necessary for the programs to know which display server to use for output.

This is known from $DISPLAY variable. Which is usually set to :0, when you perform a GUI login.

However if you are doing SSH login or using Ubuntu in headless mode or some configuration is incorrect, $DISPLAY variable will not be set.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orQn8.png)

To fix it, simply set this before launching gazebo,

```
user@ubuntu:~$ export DISPLAY=:0
user@ubuntu:~$ gazebo
```